# Dataadapter.Fill for "column1 is not belongs to table1"

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

Here issue is showing error "column1 is not belongs to table"

Here previous had one panel with table id="table1" and grid,
now i add another panel and with table id="table1" and grid,

This called method Getautocompletedata 
code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

string[] strTableAndColumnName = strAuto.Split(',');
string DB_CONN_STRING = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DB_CONN_STRING);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select " + strTableAndColumnName[1] + " from " + strTableAndColumnName[0], conn);
SqlDataAdapter da;
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds, "table1");
return ds.GetXml();
```

and  method called at js file

code:

```
function getAutoFillData(obj) {
    var ControlId = document.getElementById('autocompID');
    if (ControlId != null) {
        document.getElementById('autocompID').value = obj.id;
    }
    var strAutoFill = obj.name;
    document.getElementById('autocompID').value = strAutoFill;

    UpDateAlert.GetAutoCompleteData(strAutoFill, FillAutoCompleteData);
```

Now how to fill table2  data is dataadapter?

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific?

1) Why do you have 2 elements with the same ID?

> Here previous had one panel with table id="table1" and grid, now i add another panel and with table id="table1" and grid

2) Do you mean you want to fill table with all columns? eg.

```
String Sql = "Select\r\n";
        for (int i = 1; i < strTableAndColumnName.Length; i++)
        {
            Sql += strTableAndColumnName[i] + ",\r\n";
        }
        Sql = Sql.Remove(Sql.Length - ",\r\n".Length) + 
            " from " + strTableAndColumnName[0];
```

and so

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn);
```

Sorry for the reply, but i haven't enough reputation to add comment.

Comment: no issus but thing not same id,here two panel with differnt table and different id's

Comment: here my  doubt is how to call two id's in da.Fill(ds, "table1");?

Comment: still i am getting sam error Column 'GrossID' does not belong to table Table1.

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select " + strTableAndColumnName[1] + " from " + strTableAndColumnName[0], conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da;
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds, "table1");

            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select " + strTableAndColumnName[2] + " from " + strTableAndColumnName[0], conn);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds, "table2");

Comment: give me some time please i will test it